# One to one map $f$ equal to its power series

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, power-series

Across a difficult exercise sheet I encountered this exercise :

> Let $f$ be a continuous map from $\bar D$ the closed unit disk (in $\mathbb{C}$) to $\mathbb{C}$. We suppose that $f$ is one to one (injective) and that $f(z)= \sum_{n \geqslant 0} a_n z^n$ in $D$ (the unit open disk) where $\sum a_n z^n$ has a convergence radius equal to $1$ Show that $\sum a_n z^n$ does converge uniformly on $\bar D$

The proof is hard and involves a bit of complex analysis, and some really tricky results of Fourier analysis.

My question is the following : what is the name of this theorem and where can I find it "in context" ? Moreover, my knoledge is just undergraduate Fourier analysis, so is there a reference book for Fourier analysis (especially for Fourier series) and power series results that are not well known ? In fact I think that this theorem is not well known ^^

Thank you.

EDIT. If someone is interested in I can provide a detailed proof of this problem, I would be glad to do it if someone ask for.

Comment: I would be interested in a proof.

Comment: Remind me to do that if I forget tomorrow :)

Comment: I'm confused by the phrasing of the question. Why is the domain of $f$ a subset of $R^2$? The question seems to immediately ignore that and just treat $R^2$ as $C$ when saying $f$ is analytic. Otherwise what is the meaning of $z^n$?

Comment: You are right, it is $\mathbb{C}$ I edited.

Answer (score 1):

Well, someone asked for so there is a compact solution (I can provide more details of course) :

First, since $f$ is one to one we deduce that $f'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \bar D$. Then we set $D_r = \{ z, \; |z| \leqslant r\}$. Then if $A_r$ denotes the area of $f(D_r)$ we have : $$A_r= \iint_{f(D_r)} \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y =\iint_{D_r} |f'(x+iy)|^2 \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y = \int_{0}^{r} I(\rho) \mathrm{d} \rho$$

where $ \displaystyle I (\rho) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f'(\rho e^{i \theta})|^2\mathrm{d} \theta = 2 \pi \sum_{n \geqslant 1} (na_n \rho ^n)^2$ using Parseval-Plancherel identity.

A classical sum/integral inversion shows that : $$A_r = 2 \pi \sum_{n \geqslant 1} n|a_n|^2 r^{2n}$$

for any $r<1$. Thus for any $N,r$ we have : $$\sum_{k=1}^{N} n|a_n|^2 r^{2n} \leqslant A_1$$ Since the bound is uniform in $r$ and $N$ the convergence of $\sum n|a_n|^2$ is ensured.

Next we set $\displaystyle S(N)= \sum_{n=1}^N n|a_n|$ we can write using Cauchy-Schwarz : $$S(N) \leqslant \sqrt{\sum_{k \leqslant N} k} \sqrt{\sum_{k \leqslant N} n |a_n|^2} = \mathcal{O} (N) $$

This is the key estimate **[Q1]**

Let $g(\theta) = f(e^{i \theta})$ and $g_{r} (\theta) = f(re^{i \theta})$. By the dominated convergence theorem we can easily show that $\hat g (n) =a_n$.

Then if $F_N$ is the Fourier kernel we can set $\phi _N (\theta) = F_N * g (\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^N \left( 1- \frac{n}{N+1} \right) a_n e^{in \theta}$. We know that $\phi _N \to g$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. **[Q2]** Plus we write $\phi _N = S_N - \psi _N $ so that : $$|\psi _N (\theta) | \leqslant \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N n|a_n|}{N+1} \to 0$$ We conclude that $S_N$ converges uniformly on the circle so in the entire disk (Abel transform inside). **[Q3]**

Thanks to this short version of the proof I can ask a few questions :

**[Q1]** Where can I find "sharp" estimates like this one, on the Fourier coefficients. Because all I know is the Fourier Plancherel identity and the Cauchy integral representation of the Fourier coefficients. But I am convinced a lot of work in the direction of more accurate estimations have been done.

**[Q2]** All I know about kernels in Fourier analysis is Fejer, Dirichlet and Poisson's one. Is there a reference in this direction ? Because we see here how important the kernel regularisation is important !

**[Q3]** This fact is well knonw and often proposed as an exercise (it was the case for me). But is there a lot of propreties like that about power series ?